# Django how to call this def in all template files?

Tags: django, function, call

Hey, i need a little help with this django function. I wan't to insert it into base.html but i cant .. How ?

```
def my_friends(request):
friendships = request.user.profile.friendships.exclude(pending=True).order_by('-friend__user__last_activity_date')
friendshipsQS = friendships
results = tuplify(friendships.all(), n=3)
return render(request, 'base.html', locals())
```

Comment: Just a little friendly advice: you should review the answers provided to your previous questions and possibly accept the ones that were appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Accept Answers]

You can't just set up a view that renders `base.html` and hope everything that extends it will use that view as well.

You need to use something like a Context Processor to inject values into every context.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

```
def FriendsContextProcessor(request):
    """
    Include Friendships in all RequestContext
    """
    friendships = request.user.profile.friendships.exclude(pending=True).order_by('-friend__user__last_activity_date')
    friendshipsQS = friendships
    results = tuplify(friendships.all(), n=3)
    return { 'results': results, 'friendshipsQS': friendshipsQS }
```

add `python.dot.path.to.my.FriendsContextProcessor` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting and the dictionary returned above will be available in all `RequestContext`, which apparently `render(...)` does for you! Does that mean you're using trunk?